# uisegmentControl inside uialertview

Tags: uialertview, uisegmentedcontrol

I wanna show segment control inside uialertview.

UISegmentedControl *progress= [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

[alert addSubview:progress];
  [alert show];

I doesn't work. But If I change this as uiprogressview it shows up.but segment control is not added to alertview.

Don't know what am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you have to use adding subView in alertView's delegate method because alertView calculates its frame before showing to user.

UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello SubViews" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];

- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    CGFloat height = 25.0;

    UILabel *firstLabel = (UILabel*)[[alertView subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
    CGRect label_rect=firstLabel.frame;

    UISegmentedControl *segment=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Me",@"And",@"You",nil]];
    segment.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [segment setFrame:CGRectMake(label_rect.origin.x, label_rect.origin.y+label_rect.size.height,label_rect.size.width,height)];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(segment.frame, 0, height + 4)];
    [textField setText:@"Enter some text"];
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UIButton *okBtn=(UIButton*)[[alertView subviews] objectAtIndex:2];
    [okBtn setFrame:CGRectOffset(textField.frame, 0, height + 4)];

    [alertView addSubview:segment];
    [alertView addSubview:textField];

    alertView.frame = CGRectUnion(alertView.frame, CGRectOffset(alertView.frame, 0, 40));

}
```

output----------------

[image]

Comment: I have already sorted this out. But for your time to help me and for ur explanation . I gave one up and chosen this as best answer. Thanks for your time to help me..

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the first screenful of text [in the UIAlertView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html), you'll see this *very important* note:

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
> and does not support subclassing. **The view hierarchy for this class is
> private and must not be modified**.

Modifying something that is private and shouldn't be modified means: in the best case, potentially unexpected bad things could happen with your app in future versions of iOS; and in the worst case, your app might be rejected if Apple ever gets around to detecting which apps are mucking with the UIAlertView hierarchy.

To solve your problem, you should create your own implementation of an alert, a subclassed UIView, and add a segmented controller to *that* and use that as a UIAlertView substitute.